# Use scp to copy a file to different servers

Tags: linux, scp, file-transfer

I have to copy a file to different servers almost every day. What I usually do is:

```
scp filename user@destinationhost:/destination/folder
```

I run this same command changing the destination host over and over again until I finish all the servers. What is the best (and fastest) way to transfer the same file to those different servers?

Another drawback is that I need to enter the password over and over again, but using rsa is not an option since several people can connect to the source server.

Edit - I found loop in [commandlinefu](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/723/copy-something-to-multiple-ssh-hosts-with-a-bash-loop) that may do the trick:

```
 for h in host1 host2 host3 host4 ; { scp file user@$h:/destination_path/ ; }
```

Comment: Do you have expect on the system ?

Comment: @lain Yes, expect is installed.

Comment: Anyone knows why everyone else is ignoring scp man page specifies that you can have more than one target? `scp file host1:path host2:path host3:path ...`

Comment: Oh because last one is not the target...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are various tools which can scp files to multiple hosts (with simultaneous connections), like [pssh](https://code.google.com/archive/p/parallel-ssh/) and [kanif](http://taktuk.gforge.inria.fr/kanif/). In terms of passwords I would suggest using [agent forwarding](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/ssh-agent-forwarding.html). This allows you to keep the key on your local machine, but use it when initiating SSH connections from another host. Otherwise, the `--askpass` option to the `parallel-scp` command from [pssh](https://code.google.com/archive/p/parallel-ssh/) makes it prompt for a password to use for every host.

If you can't install a tool to do this, setup agent forwarding (by adding the `-A` option to `ssh` when connecting to the machine you're doing this on) and then run `scp` in a loop like so:

```
for HOST in server1 server2 server3; do
    scp somefile $HOST:~/somedir/
done
```

Comment: `pssh` is not installed in the server and I can't run applications that weren't provided by the sysadmin team.

Comment: @RubenPloneda, but it does sound like you have a valid reason for that tool.  You should at least consider it, and forward your request to your sysadmin team to get that installed.

Comment: Then you'll have to use SSH agent forwarding and a bash loop (see answer).

Answer (score 4):

Try doing this with an expect script e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

HOSTS="h1.lan h2.lan h3.lan"

read -p "Password: " PASSWORD


for HOST in $HOSTS
do
    expect -c "
    spawn /usr/bin/scp file user@$HOST:/destination_path/
    expect {
    "*password:*" { send $PASSWORD\r;interact }
    }
    exit
    "
done
```

The above should be fairly straight forward to adapt to your requirements.

Comment: It results in `... line 10: expect: command not found`

Comment: My fault. If you don't have `expect` installed, install it first with `sudo apt-get install expect`

Answer (score 1):

I think `sshpass` should be mentioned here.  This is my go on sending a file to multiple targets, with a required password:

```
filePath="/home/download/textToSend.txt"
ip_range=("10.10.10.1" "10.10.10.2" "10.10.10.3" "10.10.10.4")
# Start file transfer
echo "Starting file transfer to ${#ip_range[@]} units."
for ((i=0; i<${#ip_range[@]}; ++i )) ;
do
   echo "Transfering ${filePath} to ${ip_range[$i]}..."
   sshpass -p password scp -o 'StrictHostKeyChecking=no' "${filePath}" root@${ip_range[$i]}:/home/downloads&
done
wait
echo "File transfers ended"
```

Answer (score 0):

I used 'sshpt' for a similar situation. The SSH Power Tool (sshpt) enables you to execute commands and upload files to many servers simultaneously via SSH without using pre-shared keys. Uploaded files and commands can be executed directly or via sudo.